# Truth Tables and Venn Diagrams: Prove Contingent statement are consistent

Tags: truth, proof

I am trying to prove how consistent statements can be contigent. The problem i am having how to use a truth table to prove this.

Comment: What does it mean to be "contingent" ?

Comment: I think he means : Occurring or existing only if (certain other circumstances) are the case; dependent on.

Answer (score 3):

If by "consistent" you mean that a formula of propositional logic is satisfied by some truth assignment, i.e. in his truth table there is at least one row with **T** under the formula, and if by "contingent" you mean that the formula is **not** a *tautology*, i.e. it is not identically true, then to use the truth table to answer your question you have to find at least a row with **T** (for consistency) and at least a row with **F** (for not being a *tautology*, i.e. for "contingency").

Comment: "A contingent statement is a statement form which is neither a tautology nor a contradiction, but whose truth value depends upon the truth value of its component substatements." - So, yes, you're right.